# Update json with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just started out with Angular, and I did the codeschool tutorial. I took it a step further and wanted to push form data to a json file.

I'm getting the correct response where the information is posted, but the file is not being updated. I've tried this locally and on a development server.

This is my directive code:

```
//---------------------------------------//
// Lets user add a review to site
app.directive("productAddReview", function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directives/product-add-review.html',
    controller: function($http) {
        // gets a blank review
        this.review = {};

        // sets today's date as a variable
        this.review.date = Date.now();

        // adds a review
        this.addReview = function(product) {
            product.reviews.push(this.review);      // adds review to dom
            $http.post('../data/products.json', this.review) //updates json file
            this.review = {};                       // resets review upon completion
        };          
    },
    controllerAs: 'reviewCtrl',
 };
});
```

Example json response upon review submit:

```
author: "test@test.com"

body: "this is a test"

date: 1443540061192

stars:  5

Source: {"date":1443540061192,"stars":5,"body":"this is a test","author":"test@test.com"}
```

Comment: your server has to update the file. but if its just a file on disk, then nothing will happen. nothing to do with angular per se.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$http.post` will not magically update your file. It will make a `POST` request to a given address. It means, that you need to have a server, that will handle your request.

Consider, that browsers are not allowed to manipulate files on your disk.